# Low-level implementation of double value in Java and C#

Tags: c#, java, database, double

I am in front of a tough problem. I want read data from a sqlite database by C#. The data field in the database has a type of blob. This field contains double values (also has other type of values such as text and int) written by Java. I need read the double values out by C#.

I am sorry that I made a terrible mistake in the question. I read the double values in Java by create a ByteBuffer initialized by the blob stream which is read from database. And there is no counterpart ByteBuffer data struct in C#, so I use the code below to get the double value from 8 bytes stream.

```
public double getDouble()
{
    if(CURRENT_POSITION + 7 >= CURRENT_LENGTH)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    double ret = (double)(TEMP_BYTE_ARRAY[CURRENT_POSITION + 7] << 56 |
                          TEMP_BYTE_ARRAY[CURRENT_POSITION + 6] << 48 |
                          TEMP_BYTE_ARRAY[CURRENT_POSITION + 5] << 40 |
    .....
    );
    return ret;
}
```

But I can't get the right double value from the blob field by C# using the same Code. Can anyone give me some advices about how to convert the binary style double value defined by Java to C# double value?

By the way, because the blob field compressed a lot of other types of values I can't change the struct of the database. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Are you really sure that's the code you want on the Java side? That's always going to give an integer...

Comment: That's still not going to produce any non-integer values... if you're expecting it to, you really need to look at what you're doing...

Comment: Maybe you should post an example value from the database and what value we should expect to read from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.todouble.aspx):

```
double ret = BitConverter.ToDouble(TEMP_BYTE_ARRAY, CURRENT_POSITION);
```

The code you posted just creates an integer and converts the integer into a double, which is not what you want.

**Alternitavely**, you can get the same functionality as a ByteBuffer by creating a [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) over a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). For example:

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(TEMP_BYTE_ARRAY);
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(memStream);

//read data
double a = reader.ReadDouble();
int b = reader.ReadInt();
string c = reader.ReadString();
```